# How to Make Echo Random Image

Tags: image

I am looking to have posts echo a random image from, say, a selection of 3 images.

I want it to echo img1 or img2 or img3.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
echo '<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image-default.png" />' || echo '<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image-default.png" />';
```

How can I make this serve up a random picture from a selection?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all the image list and push to an array
2. using `array_rand` to pick a random image
3. echo it as you done.

```html
$imageStack = [];
array_push($imageStack, '<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image-default-1.png" />');
array_push($imageStack, '<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image-default-2.png" />');
array_push($imageStack, '<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image-default-3.png" />');
print_r($imageStack);
echo 'random';
$displayImage = array_rand($imageStack);
print_r($imageStack[$displayImage]);
```